# How to load a ERB, edit and save it to the disk using Rails and ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

Ok, imagine I have a template file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  <%= "ServerName #{@user[:domain]}" %>
  <%= "ServerAlias #{@user[:domain]}" &>
  DocumentRoot "/my/app/path"
  ErrorLog <%= "/private/var/log/apache2/#{@user[:domain]}-error_log" %>
  CustomLog <%= "/private/var/log/apache2/#{@user[:domain]}-access_log" %> common
  <Directory "/my/app/path">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And I would like to load this file, replace the variable with actual data and save it to a file?

I know the gist of read and save files to disk with Ruby, but I'm not sure how to replace the variables with actual data while saving it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

@foo = "world"
I think you need ERB.new("Hello <%= @foo%>").result # "Hello world"

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html#method-i-result

Comment: But how do I pass the `@user` variable into it?

Comment: @foo is a variable in the example